# Remove page title on the home page with function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to php and I am trying to remove a page title on the homepage with a function in wordpress. I searched a lot for this and couldn't find an answer. I don't want to use css display:none;. I came up with this in the functions.php but it does not work.

```
function remove_title() {
    if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
        $title = '';
    } else {
        return = $title ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check my code, by any chance?

Comment: It works! Thank you. Why do I have to use add_filter?

Comment: [**`the_title`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) is a filter applied to the post title retrieved from the database, prior to printing on the screen. In some cases (such as when the_title is used), the title can be suppressed by returning a false value (e.g. NULL, FALSE or the empty string) from the filter function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_page_title', 10, 2 );

function remove_page_title( $title, $id ) {
    if( is_home() || is_front_page() )
        return '';

    return $title;
}
```

Would you please try above code?

Comment: This will also remove menu titles. Should be   if ((is_home()||is_front_page()) && in_the_loop())

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you like to go with the plugin then [Hide title](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-title/) plugin can do the job. It hides the title on pages and posts via the edit post screen.

Comment: The OP specified he'd like to do it in the functions.php file (not via plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Though a solution has already been posted, I wanted to bring up that the `the_title()` is already initiated at the page.php level (or in any template part or partial view within it). The current solution removes the title content and returns a title with value "Untitled". It basically, thinks the page hasn't bene titled. Not a good solutions in my opinion

To remove it programmatically, you have to go to where the page title is initiated in page.php and

replace

```
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
```

with

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page() || is_page("any_additional_page")){
   // do nothing
} else {
   the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
}
```

This method is particularly helpful when you need to give different classes to each page title depending on the pages. For example, your home page, your content pages, and your shop pages may all look different or some could be intentionally omitted